# User does not have permission to use the ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS option

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, partition

Trying to use switch partition in one of the Stored Procedures. We are getting the below error:

> User does not have permission to use the ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS option.

The user has ALTER ANY permission as well.

Here is the query:

```
BEGIN TRY
           BEGIN TRANSACTION
                DELETE FROM TableBackup
                
                ALTER TABLE TableMain SWITCH PARTITION 1 
                         TO TableBackup PARTITION 1
                       WITH ( WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY ( MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS ));  

                ALTER TABLE TableTemp SWITCH PARTITION 1 
                         TO TableMain PARTITION 1;
            COMMIT
        END TRY
```

1. Should I add -  `WITH ( WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY ( MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS ));`  for the 2nd switch also?
2. Should I consider changing `ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = NONE`?

Comment: why not truncate table tableBackup? Also, do you need abort after wait?

Comment: Could do `ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = SELF` you should have permissions for that.

Comment: The user would require ALTER ANY CONNECTION to kill the other sessions.  Just like Kill.